# How to get the index of np.maximum?

Tags: python, numpy

I know `np.maximum` computes the element-wise maximum, e.g.

```
>>> b = np.array([3, 6, 1])
>>> c = np.array([4, 2, 9])
>>> np.maximum(b, c)
array([4, 6, 9])
```

But is there any way to get the index as well? like in the above example, I also want something like this where each tuple denote (which array, index), it could be tuple or dictionary or something else. And also it would be great if it could work on 3d array, like the input two arrays are 3d arrays.

```
array([(1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could stack the two 1d-arrays to get a 2d-array and use `argmax`:

```
arr = np.vstack((b, c))
indices = np.argmax(arr, axis=0)
```

This will give you a list of integers, not tuples, but as you know that you compare per column, the last elements of each tuple are unnecessary anyway. They are just ascending integers starting at 0. If you really need them, though, you could just add

```
indices = list(zip(indices, range(len(b)))
```

Comment: Hi thanks this is a good idea, does it work for 3d array as well? for example both `b` and `c` are `256x256x256` array? just stack them into one `256x256x256x2` and do `np.argmax` at the last axis?

Comment: @QiminChen Just try it. But I don't see any reason why that shouldn't work. You could test it with small 2d-arrays first to be able to properly check the results. And if that works it should be applicable to arrays of arbitrary dimensions.